# Binary voting and the effect of a hypothetical policy change

Tags: logit, politics

Let's say that we know the outcome of a vote for choosing A or B and this is based on some demographic factors.

We estimate $ln\frac{P}{1-P}=\beta_0+\beta_1Dem_1+\beta_2Dem_2+\beta_3Dem_3$,

where $P$ the probability of choosing A and $Dem_i$ demographic factors, e.g. people that completed secondary education.

We suspect that if education spending increased by $S$ and the number of people completing secondary education was higher, $P$ would change and the outcome of the vote would be different. What we don't know is how effective this policy would be, and how their number would change.

What is an appropriate method to get around this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If we know that there is a link $S \to Perm_1 \to P$ but we don't know the relationship $S \to Perm_1$, then we look at [Structural Equation Modelling](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/what-is-a-latent-variable/).

What is it and why is it useful?

> The nature of the latent variable is intrinsically related to the nature of the indicator variables used to define them. In the most usual case, we structure the model so that the indicators are “effects” of the latent variable, like in the case of the common factor analysis.
>
> The idea is that the value of the latent variable caused people to respond as they did on the observed indicators.

How is this done?

> On a technical note, estimation of a latent variable is done by analyzing the variance and covariance of the indicators. The measurement model of a latent variable with effect indicators is the set of relationships (modeled as equations) in which the latent variable is set as the predictor of the indicators.